# Oracle Linq2Sql weird behavior when comparing an empty string

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Using EF6 with Oracle drivers ver. 4.122.1.0. We've implemented essentially the same query in two slightly different ways:

```
var foo1 = _someContext
            .SOME_TABLE
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.SOME_STRING_COLUMN != null && x.SOME_STRING_COLUMN.Trim() != "") //aka string.isnullorwhitespace
            .ToString();
```

vS:

```
var foo2 = _someContext
            .SOME_TABLE
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.SOME_STRING_COLUMN != null && x.SOME_STRING_COLUMN.Trim() != string.Empty) //aka string.isnullorwhitespace
            .ToString();
```

From these two implementations only the second one yields the desired results when SOME_STRING_COLUMN is indeed not null or whitespace-only. The first one returns null. Here are the where clauses generated by these two sql queries:

```
    ("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN" IS NOT NULL)
AND (
    NOT (
                ( (LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN"))) = :p__linq__0 )
            AND (
                    (
                        CASE WHEN (LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN")) IS NULL)
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    ) = (CASE WHEN (:p__linq__0 IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            )
    )
)

======================================================================

    ("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN" IS NOT NULL)
AND (
    NOT (
                ( '' = (LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN")))      )
            AND ( LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN")) IS NOT NULL )
    )
)
```

Is this a bug in the Oracle driver or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, an empty string `''` is a `NULL` value. So your second statement:

```
( '' = (LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN")))      )
```

is the same as:

```
( NULL = (LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN")))      )
```

Since `NULL = <anything>` is always false then:

```
("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN" IS NOT NULL)
AND (
    NOT (
                ( '' = (LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN")))      )
            AND ( LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN")) IS NOT NULL )
    )
)
```

Is the same as:

```
("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN" IS NOT NULL)
AND ( NOT ( FALSE AND <anything> ) )
```

Which can be simplified to just the first condition:

```
("Extent1"."SOME_STRING_COLUMN" IS NOT NULL)
```

And does not test for the absence of white space, just that the value is not null.

Comment: The question is why would the Oracle driver generate two different where-clauses (with one of them being completely erroneous) in sql despite the fact that "" and string.Empty are virtually the exact same thing.